# How to handle a single quote character while using openCsv

Tags: opencsv

I have a reader which is defined as follows:

```
    CSVReader csvReader =new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream), ',', '\'');
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String[] line;
    if (SPECIAL_CHARS == null || SPECIAL_CHARS.length == 0) {
        return inputStream;
    }
    String[] stringArrSpecialChars = new String(SPECIAL_CHARS).split("");

    while ((line = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
          //do somthing
    }
```

how ever it throws this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Unterminated quoted field at end of CSV line. Beginning of lost text: [D'Olra
```

when it encounter a CSV cell with: D'Olra

Any advise ?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by replacing the first line with:

```
char charThatWillNotAppearInText = 127;
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream), ',', charThatWillNotAppearInText);
```

This is a workaround that disable the 'quotechar' option under the assumption that char with 127 will never be part of the input CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Use OpenCSV as:

```
com.opencsv.CSVParser parser = new CSVParserBuilder().withIgnoreQuotations(true).withSeparator('|').build()
```